# How to get relational data in Symfony?

Tags: orm, relational-database, symfony

I have created two Entities. 
1. Bookings
2. Restaurants

While generating booking inquiry, user will also select one restaurant from drop down list of all restaurants. So I have set Many2one relation in Bookings Entity.

```
class Bookings
{ 

...

 /**
  * @var int
  */
 /**
  * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Restaurants", inversedBy="restaurant_id")
  * @JoinColumn(name="restaurant_id", referencedColumnName="id",  onDelete="CASCADE")
  */
    private $restaurantId;

...

public function __construct() {
     $this->restaurantId = new ArrayCollection();
}

...


}
```

So one restaurant is associated with each booking inquiry and multiple booking inquiries will be associated with every booking.

Now while fetching list of all booking inquiries from controller. I am getting only bookings table details. but how can I also get associated restaurant details like id and res_name along with every booking inquiry.

below is the query for fetching all booking inquiries.

```
$bookings = $this->getDoctrine()
                   ->getRepository('AppBundle:Bookings')
                   ->findAll();
```

but this query is returning only booking details not restaurant details, though I have set relationship in bookings entity. How can I get restaurant details along with every booking inquiry automatically in result set.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you straight away that your ManyToOne looks wrong:

```
 /**
  * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Restaurants", inversedBy="restaurant_id")
  * @JoinColumn(name="restaurant_id", referencedColumnName="id",  onDelete="CASCADE")
  */
```

inversedby refers to the property which contains the OneToMany collection, which in your case would not be restaurant_id, it would be bookings.

So correctly:

```
 /**
  * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Restaurants", inversedBy="bookings")
  * @JoinColumn(name="restaurant_id", referencedColumnName="id",  onDelete="CASCADE")
  */

protected $restaurant; // id not needed here, you're referencing a whole entity in doctrine not a single id
```

And Restaraunt entity should look something like:

```
/**
 * Booking entity collection
 *
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Booking", mappedBy="restaurant")
 */
protected $bookings;
```

I recommend you read the [association mapping documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) and make sure you have a thorough understanding how relations in doctrine work.

Comment: Hi Richard, Thanks for solution. I tried this but still not its giving restaurant details in result set.

Comment: You should be able to call $booking->getRestaurant() on an instance of Booking and that *should* return a Restaurant instance.  If you want a list of  Restaurants you'll need to add that to your form as an entity type: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Answer (score 0):

After doing Rnd for an hours, I discovered that the entities were not using PHP annotations, but rather the XML versions. So I added proper relations setting in xml file and its working now.